# How to read json post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to migrate a .net app to rails and in one of the .net rest controllers, there's method that receives a json post and converts it to a string.  Here's the code.

```
string json = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I then parse out the properties as such...

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken applicant = result["applicant"];
JToken resume = applicant["resume"];
JToken resumeJson = resume["json"];
JToken resumeFile = resume["file"];
JToken name = applicant["fullName"];
```

Since the post body is the json data, how do you receive and parse that in rails?  Here's some sample json we'd receive.

```
{
    "id":"0d9393kd9c9fkdjreridfjd019sdklfj",
    "job":{
            "jobId":"1234",
            "jobTitle":"test job",
            "jobLocation":"Cleveland, OH",
            "jobUrl":"http://www.myjobsite.com",
            "jobMeta":"?jid=123&"
        },
        "applicant":{
            "fullName":"Full Name",
            "firstName":"Full",
            "lastName":"Name",
            "coverletter":"Hello, I'm looking for a job",
            "email":"applicant@test.com",
            "phoneNumber":"(123) 123-1234",
            "resume":{
                "file":{
                        "data":"test data here",
                        "fileName":"test_resume.pdf",
                        "contentType":"application/octet-stream"
                },
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON output, so that it'll be easier to show you how to do read it in Rails?

Comment: this is your [tool](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) to get it done. This tool will give you [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html) after parsing,,

Comment: That's assuming that I have a string of json to begin with though right?  I first need to know how to get the json from the post body.

Comment: Nevermind, I eventually found that rails is already parsing all of this for me.